# Eclipse don't see headers to include :/

Tags: android-ndk, eclipse-cdt

What can be wrong in my project properties if eclipse don't see headers I include ? I have good include paths, i can see them in window with includes hierarchy.

[image][image]

But in source editor there is problem :/

[image]
[image]

In properties I have good paths:

[image]

This problem came suddenly :/ Yesterday I could build my project without any problems, but now there is some problem :/ Project isn't under version control, so I can't revert to yesterday's source:/

Comment: Good idea to fix it and put it under version control so this doesn't happen again...

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but your last screenshot seems to be showing the include paths s for C - are the include paths for C++ the same?

Comment: You know what, that is probably the solution!!!

Comment: I don't have any paths for c++, but I don't change anything in properties. I add for test to c++, but it still don't work :/

Comment: @ Michael: thanks for that. Had the same problem and couldn't find a hint anywhere. It is a bit confusing because eclipse lets you add a path to all 3 (Assembly, Gnu C, Gnu C++) but if you update it it will only update the selected language. (Which is Assembly by default)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes eclipse uses a different working directory that you expect, so you kind of have to play around with relative paths a little. Try putting a ../ In front of the directory, perhaps that will put it in scope, but I think that there is a way to find out the build directory other than guessing. Project -> properties -> C++ build and look around. Also, we can't help you much if you don't host is somewhere where we can download it... If you do that I promise you I will fix it and post the solution!